# Windows Phone 7 Mango - Local Database - SQL CE 4.0

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce-4

I did not use SQL CE 3.5 for Windows Mobile as I need to include some binaries of SQL CE 3.5 (having size of > 3 MB) in my application setup.

Now, I am developing for Windows Phone 7. With Mango realease, we have support for Local Database. Do we need to include any binary that increases the size of final application? If yes, what is the footprint of those binaries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be no need to include any extra binaries.

Comment: With WinMo the database needed to be installed separately and wasn't part of the framework. With Windows Phone Mango the DB support is part of the framework. Ergo no extra libraries to install. To verify this, create an app which uses the DB and then see which libraries are included in the XAP. I haven't got Mango installed on this machine so can't check myself.

Comment: SQL CE is already on the Phone (the binaries ae actually there in the original Phone 7, just not accessible).  You will not have to distribute anything extra for that support.